# How to Reorder columns of excel file using XLSX library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, xlsx

I am using XLSX library to export a data array into an excel file, the exporting things works fine but i can't figure out how to reorder the columns of the excel file.

This is the code that i am using to export the file.

```
export const generateXLSX = (fileName: string, data: ILocation[]) => {
  /* generate worksheet from array */
  const ws = utils.json_to_sheet(data);
  /* create workbook and append worksheet */
  const wb = utils.book_new();
  utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Data');
  /* export to XLSX */
  writeFile(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
};
```

I have a dataset like this and i need to order this from monday to sunday, as you can see currently it is randomly placed

[image: sample excel sheet]

I searched for a way to order these columns but i could't find a way to do it.